# Upgrade PHP to 5.2.12 on CentOS using yum

Tags: php, upgrade, centos

I tried to find a simple way to upgrade PHP on my CentOS5 machine using `yum` instead of downloading the source and compiling it again myself (I did it last time, but it's really difficult to get all the compile configurations same as CentOS's default). Anyway, I finally use the methods listed here:
http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP

Now, the command `php -v` shows the version is already 5.2.11 (which I needed) , but it always contains many warnings like:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize   module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

I think it basically means that I need to recompile these four modules, how could I do that? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy, you need to add more upto date yum repository and then upgrade.

one example is here.

```
cat >> /etc/yum.repos.d/utterramblings.repo <<END
[utterramblings]
name=Jason's Utter Ramblings Repo
baseurl=http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/EL5/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/RPM-GPG-KEY-jlitka
```

After this you would get latest versions of php and other extensions. It works!!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not installed all at once, it's modular.  So you have things just like you listed that are designed for a different version of PHP.  You will need to install all the plugins you are using for your implementation for the version of PHP you have installed.

Short answer, if you want a REALLY up to date PHP version, don't use CentOS.  It's just a pain.  CentOS is about stability, not cutting edge software.  Use Ubuntu or Debian.

Long answer, your best option hands down is to compile from source or to find a repository that provides PHP 5.1.whatyouneed.  I would advise against using a repository unless you are VERY sure that it comes from a reputable source.

If I was to do this I'd compile PHP from the source.  Here is a link to get you started: http://www.wolflabs.org/2008/12/08/installing-php-from-source-on-centos-x86_64-w-apache/

Comment: I agree with you. however, I have to stick with CentOS (it's the productions server environment, the developer's better to be the same). Actually, I just found out that I could use 'yum upgrade php-mssql php-mcrypt' to remove the warnings, but for other two, I don't which two modules I should call.

Answer (score 0):

You should grab [the SRPM](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/SRPMS/php-5.1.6-23.2.el5_3.src.rpm), replace the tarball, and rebuild it. You may want to grab [the "extras" SRPM](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/extras/SRPMS/php-extras-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.src.rpm) as well if you need anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

here is repo configuration I've used to upgrade PHP on CentOS 5 (look for Enterprise Linux 5 in the text)
http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

Answer (score 0):

Try

> pecl install fileinfo readline memcache

And this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`pecl install memcache`

Worked for me running Centos 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I followed a CentOS wiki on how to upgrade PHP using a testing repository:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2

I was getting errors for fileinfo and memcache, so I tried:

```
pecl install fileinfo memcache
```

...and all of the warnings vanished.